# What could be the reason why a batch command periodically hangs?

Tags: batch-file

Good day! There are quite a few batch commands that are used to trigger events on three servers we have. I'm not really familiar with batch commands, but I have written a few. My problem is, I wrote a very simple batch command that calls and runs an .EXE file that automatically applies batches on a POS Server. Here is the command;

```
C:\grocery\sm2baply.exe /a
```

This has been working fine for weeks, but lately it just hangs until the next schedule task is ran with the same command and it overrides this. But the batches that should have been applied were not. About 3 out of 7 days it doesn't work.

Can someone help me please?

Thanks.

Comment: `sm2baply` and/or associated files is likely to be the problem.   The OS could be corrupted in some way too.  Test it on a different machine to see if the PC/OS is an issue here,

Comment: Maybe this question is better off on [serverfault](http://serverfault.com)

Comment: If it sometimes works and other times does not, it is possible that the file it is patching is sometimes in use and therefore cannot be patched at that moment.  Perhaps that is what is causing the patch process to periodically hang...

Answer (score 0):

Schedule Tasks keep a log of what happened. So read the log.

In Scheduled Tasks select your task. History tab.  EG one of mine failed with this.

```
- System 

  - Provider 

   [ Name]  Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler 
   [ Guid]  {de7b24ea-73c8-4a09-985d-5bdadcfa9017} 

   EventID 202 

   Version 0 

   Level 2 

   Task 202 

   Opcode 102 

   Keywords 0x8000000000000000 

  - TimeCreated 

   [ SystemTime]  2014-07-27T21:00:04.786Z 

   EventRecordID 2008255 

  - Correlation 

   [ ActivityID]  {99694429-2673-4F4F-92E2-F55EDB9A20AC} 

  - Execution 

   [ ProcessID]  1700 
   [ ThreadID]  3140 

   Channel Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler/Operational 

   Computer Serenity 

  - Security 

   [ UserID]  S-1-5-21-2820837959-2753176274-143444667-1000 


- EventData 

  TaskName \Alarm2 
  TaskInstanceId {99694429-2673-4F4F-92E2-F55EDB9A20AC} 
  ActionName Hi 
  ResultCode 2147746317
```

`2147746317` = `0x8004020d` which is

```
//
// MessageId: EVENT_E_CANT_MODIFY_OR_DELETE_UNCONFIGURED_OBJECT
//
// MessageText:
//
// Cannot modify or delete an object that was not added using the COM+ Admin SDK
//
#define EVENT_E_CANT_MODIFY_OR_DELETE_UNCONFIGURED_OBJECT _HRESULT_TYPEDEF_(0x8004020DL)
```

If that doesn't work you need to monitor your batch. Echoing out things during execution (in case it's hanging). EG

```
Copy somefile.ext someotherfile.ext
echo Up to copy >> program.log
```

You can also start in a debugger.

windbg or ntsd (ntsd is a console program and maybe installed). Both are also from Debugging Tools For Windows.

Download and install Debugging Tools for Windows

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/hh852363

Install the Windows SDK but just choose the debugging tools.

Create a folder called `Symbols` in `C:\`

Start `Windbg`. *File* menu - *Symbol File Path* and enter

```
srv*C:\symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
```

then

```
windbg -o -g -G c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /k batfile.bat
```

You can press **F12** to stop it and kb will show the call stack (g continues the program). If there's errors it will also stop and show them.